# Differentiability of a map into $\wedge T^*M$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, differential-forms

Let $M$ a differentiable manifold and $p \in M$. Consider $(U;x_1, \dots, x_n)$ a coordinated  system around $p$. $\{dx_\phi\}_\phi$ with $\phi \in \cal{P}(\{1, \dots n\})$, $dx_\phi=dx_{i1} \wedge \dots \wedge dx_{in}$ if $\phi=i1, \dots,in$ and $dx_\phi=1$ if $\phi=\emptyset$ isa basis of $\wedge T^*M$. Consider $a_\phi \in \cal{C}^\infty(U)$.

How can I show that 
$p \longrightarrow \sum da_\phi|_p \wedge dx_\phi|_p$ is differentiable?

Comment: You need charts on the exterior algebra bundle, as with every other check of differentiability.

Comment: How can I define charts in the exterior algebra bundle? I know I should use the basis of the space and the natural projection, but I'm not sure of how to define them explicitily.

Comment: Well, then that should be your question :-)